# How to know if the launcher activity is started by clicking on notification on system tray Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

How can I detect launcher activity is called by clicking on notification on system tray, I am using firebase.

Comment: From where are you creating and sending the notification?

Comment: @jaibatrik lets say from firebase console.

Comment: I think you have to send some custom data payload and have to handle it in onMessageReceived method in client. Generate the PendingIntent for the Activity based on the payload.

Answer (score 0):

For this have to sent key and value pair (payload data) which is available in advance options in firebase console.

after this when you click on notification you get value by using key.

for example:- 
   if you use "Id" as a key then u get value of Id like this 
   String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("Id");

if getIntent().getExtras() is null then activity is not open from notification, otherwise from notification on system tray.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do that just use **DATA** message . 
it will call **onMessageReceived() method**. so you can handle it over there.

don't use Notification message for it.

**Notification** message is handle by **system tray** so you have to use **getIntent().getExtras()**  on splash activity and mov..

so simple solution is this.

```
{
          "registration_ids": [
                            "fcm token 1",
                            "fcm token 2",
                            "fcm token 3"
                        ],
          "data": {
                    "message": "msg"
                  }
        }
```

---

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

   String = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
  // and more keys
 // same as get your message and manage click event over here.

    }
```